# Is there a way to replace spaces in a sentence with ellipses in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, file

I would like to know how to replace all spaces in different sentences in a txt file with ellipses.

For example:

- Original sentence: `Hi my name is Joseph.`
- Modified sentence: `Hi... my... name... is... Joseph...`

The text structure is the following:

- sentence 1.
- sentence 2.
- sentence 3.
- sentence 4.
- .......

(Each sentence ends with a dot). I have made a code but it only works from a manually typed sentence:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {  
    char ch = getchar();

    while (ch != EOF) {
        if (ch != '\n' && ch != ' ') {
            putchar(ch);
            ch = getchar();    
        }
        else {   
            printf("... ");
            while (ch == '\n' || ch == ' ') {
                ch = getchar();
            }  
        }  
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how to modify this code to read the sentences from the file and make the changes with the dots?

Comment: Your example does not _replace_ but _adds_ a `'...'` before the space.  What should happen with 2 adjoining spaces? `"... ... "` or what?

Comment: Code replaces `' '` **and** `'\n'`, yet stated goal is only _spaces_.  If goal truly includes `'\n'`, why not also all whitespace like `'\t'`, `'\r'`, ...?

Comment: Your example appears to replace a full stop (period, dot) at the end of a sentence with triple dots — is there also spacing there?  What happens if the sentences are not one per line — if there are two or three sentences on one line, or if there are multiple lines for a single sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't want to bother doing the file manipulation in your code.  The shell does a great job handling file redirections, and you should use it.  If you do want to do the file manipulation code, don't try writing back to the original file.  There is far too much risk of data corruption if you try to edit files.  Treat files as if they are immutable.  Instead, write to a temporary file and then move the temp file over the original if you wish.  Doing so is almost always want you actually want.  You don't really care if the resulting file is the same as the original; you just care that it has the same name in the file system.  Replacing all spaces with `...` can be accomplished with the code below.  If you're going to also replace newlines, you should probably replace all white space, so I've chosen to just replace spaces as in the problem statement.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
FILE * xmkstemp(char * template, char *mode);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ch;
    char template[] = "/tmp/tmpfile.XXXXXXX";
    const char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin";
    FILE *ifp = argc > 1 ? xfopen(path, "r") : stdin;
    char *tmp_path = argc > 1 ? template : "stdout";
    FILE *ofp = argc > 1 ? xmkstemp(template, "w") : stdout;

    while( (ch = getc(ifp)) != EOF ){
        int rv = ch != ' ' ? fputc(ch, ofp) : fputs("...", ofp);
        if( rv == EOF ){
            perror(tmp_path);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    if( ferror(ifp) ){
        perror(path);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if( fclose(ofp) ){
        perror(tmp_path);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if( argc > 1 && rename(tmp_path, path) ){
        int errno_sav = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "rename %s -> ", tmp_path);
        errno = errno_sav;
        perror(path);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return 0;
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :
        *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;
    if( fp == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}

FILE *
xmkstemp(char * template, char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int fd = mkstemp(template);
    if( fd == -1 ){
        perror("mkstemp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fp = fdopen(fd, mode);
    if( fp == NULL ){
        perror(template);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how to modify this code to read the sentences from the file

Two ways:

1. Use shell redirection, e.g. `./a.out < input.txt`
2. Use `fopen`, `fgets`, `fclose`. See [man fopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong type**

`getchar()` returns an `int` in the `unsigned char` range or the negative `EOF`.  Those 257 different values can not be saved distinctively in a `char`.  Use `int` or risk infinite loops or stopping too soon.

```
// char ch = getchar();
int ch = getchar();
```

**To read/edit/write same file**

- Read from file1 (`fopen(... "r")`), adjust `" "` into `"..."`, write result to a new file2 opened with (`fopen(... "w")`).
- Close files (`fclose()`).
- If successful, `rename()` file1 into file_temp.  Rename file2 to file1.
- If successful, delete file_temp (`remove()`).

The important thing is to not delete the data of old file until after the new file is successfully made and named - this aids in error recovery.  Check the return values of the various FILE functions looking for errors.